# Platform Core Event Bus throwing DataIntegrationException

Tags: grails

I'm using the plugin Platform Core and the module of Event Bus. I need to add some domains assync, but i force sync to test, in my database but de exception DataIntegrityViolation is throwed everytime i tried to save(). That is the domain structure:

```
  class Alocacao {
    static belongsTo = [tipoUnidade: TipoUnidade]
    //Anothers attrs and constraints
}

class TipoUnidade {

    static belongsTo = [ estabelecimento : Estabelecimento];    

    static hasMany = [alocacoes: Alocacao];

    List<Alocacao> alocacoes

    //Constraints and fields...

}
```

In my controller i have this code:

```
tipoUnidadeService.save(tipoUnidadeInstance)
event('criarAlocacaoQuartoEvent', tipoUnidadeInstance, [fork: false])
```

And in my event listener this:

```
class AlocacaoService {

@Listener(topic="criarAlocacaoQuartoEvent", namespace="app")
def defaultAlocacaoCreator(EventMessage<TipoUnidade> message) {
   Canal canalSist = Canal.findByNomeIlike("%manual%")
   TipoUnidade quarto = TipoUnidade.get(message.data.id)
   def alocacaoSistema = new Alocacao(exclusivo: 0, nExclusivo: 0, data: tmp.toDate(), canal: canalSist, tipoUnidade: quarto).save(failOnError: true) //EXCEPTION!!
}
}
```

I don't know what's happen with that code.

This is the entire exception:

```
util.JDBCExceptionReporter SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
util.JDBCExceptionReporter Column 'tipo_unidade_id' cannot be null
services.AlocacaoService could not insert: [br.com.qreserva.portal.domains.Alocacao]; SQL [insert into alocacao (version, canal_id, data, date_created, exclusivo, n_exclusivo, tipo_unidade_id, alocacoes_idx) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [br.com.qreserva.portal.domains.Alocacao]
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not insert: [br.com.qreserva.portal.domains.Alocacao]; SQL [insert into alocacao (version, canal_id, data, date_created, exclusivo, n_exclusivo, tipo_unidade_id, alocacoes_idx) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [br.com.qreserva.portal.domains.Alocacao]
    at br.com.qreserva.portal.services.AlocacaoService.defaultAlocacaoCreator(AlocacaoService.groovy:178)
    at org.grails.plugin.platform.events.registry.DefaultEventsRegistry$ListenerHandler.invoke(DefaultEventsRegistry.java:238)
    at org.grails.plugin.platform.events.registry.DefaultEventsRegistry.invokeListeners(DefaultEventsRegistry.java:160)
    at org.grails.plugin.platform.events.publisher.DefaultEventsPublisher.event(DefaultEventsPublisher.java:79)
    at org.grails.plugin.platform.events.EventsImpl.event(EventsImpl.groovy:154)
    at org.grails.plugin.platform.events.EventsImpl$_closure1_closure5_closure9.doCall(EventsImpl.groovy:83)
    at br.com.qreserva.portal.controllers.TipoUnidadeController.salvar(TipoUnidadeController.groovy:126)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [br.com.qreserva.portal.domains.Alocacao]
    ... 10 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'tipo_unidade_id' cannot be null
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1015)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2542)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1734)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2019)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1937)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1922)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.PreparedStatementHandle.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementHandle.java:203)
    ... 10 more
```

**[EDIT]**

I create this [git project](https://github.com/eduardofb/grailsAssyncInsert) to illustrate my problem and the same errors occurs

**[SOLUTION]**
I solved this using the addTo* attrs in belongsTo class. But why this works i have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

The core problem is

```
MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'tipo_unidade_id' cannot be null
```

That column is the foreign key for the `tipoUnidade` variable (the camel-case `tipoUnidade` becomes `tipo_unidade` as a column name, and has the `_id` suffix added because it's a FK) so that implies that the value there is null, meaning that `TipoUnidade.get(message.data.id)` returned null. This will happen if `message.data.id` is null (possibly because `message.data` is not null but not saved yet?), or if there's no record for that id.

Since you're working with async code, my guess is that it's a timing issue, and the `message.data` value isn't saved yet, but you're trying to load a value based on it having been inserted.

Check the values, and consider turning on SQL logging so you can see the insertion and retrieval order for the items.

Comment: Thx to reply Burt. The TipoUnidade.get(message.data.id) return a value and the sql log confirm the tipoUnidadeInstance are persisted on DB. I not understand the message of nullable. SQL log: Hibernate: insert into tipo_unidade(...). I tried the withNewTransacion and whitSession but i have same result.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with EventBus. The problem is that EventBus works with threads. I suppose you use Transactions too. The both objects were created in two different threads and hibernate can't can't save one of them because the other is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Based on response of Burt i make a workaround and for some reason using the addTo* resolve the problem.

```
TipoUnidade quarto = TipoUnidade.get(message.data.id)
quarto.addToAlocacoes(new Alocacao(exclusivo: 0, nExclusivo: 0, data: tmp.toDate(), canal: canalSist))
quarto.save(failOnError: true)
```

Thx.